# Gráfico é gerado mas não mostra os dados, matplotlib

Tags: python

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Sou iniciante em Python, não estou achando o motivo para o gráfico ser gerado em branco.Como posso declarar isso para o plt?[image: Gráfico em branco]

Comment: Amigo, sem o código não conseguimos te ajudar

Comment: Realmente não havia, postado o código, obrigado! agora esta completo.

Comment: As variáveis `country`, `start_dt` e `end_dt` são strings. Qual era o resultado esperado para a tentativa de "plotar 3 strings"?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Você colocou uma imagem do código e/ou mensagem de erro. Apesar de parecer uma boa ideia, não é! Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar o código e alterar algo dentro. Clique no link [edit] e **coloque o código/erro como texto**. Veja mais sobre isso nesses links - [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/3774), [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7816/3774)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme [documentação](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html) do Matplotlib, a representação de um gráfico baseado em data e valor, é possível através do uso de dois `Arrays`, exemplo:

```
datas = ['01/02', '02/02', '03/02']
mortes = [2, 10, 35]

plt.plot(datas, mortes)
plt.xlabel('Data')
plt.ylabel('Mortes')
plt.show()
```

Dessa forma, basta pegar os valores obtidos do JSON, atribuí-los no `Array` e apresentá-los.